# GUI programs won't open in an ssh server. ssh -X and downloading XQuartz have not helped

Tags: user-interface, unix, ssh, initialization, remote-server

So I use a remote server for some of my schoolwork and have no trouble logging onto the machine and navigating. The problem arises when I attempt to run a software that uses a GUI called ds9. It's used for image processing but I don't think that is relevant. Anyways, I've tried `ssh -X username@university.edu`, I've downloaded XQuartz, and I've made sure XQuartz's Security preferences are all checked. Still, I receive the same error message: `Application initialization failed: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
Unable to initialize window system.`

I would be extremely grateful if anybody could identify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It may happened that you set a wrong DISPLAY env. var. at login time on the server. In general, `ssh -X` set the value to something like `DISPLAY=localhost:10.0` (a tunnel set up by `ssh` in between your server and your local machine).